# Does style of vf page apply to called vf component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, css, html

if a vf page has the style defined at top of page

```
<style>
                @page {
                    /* size: 8.5in 11in; */
                    size: A4 landscape;
                    margin-top: 1cm;
                    margin-bottom: 1cm;
                    margin-left: 1cm;
                    margin-right: 1cm;
                }
                * {
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px;
                }

               
                p {
                font-size: 12px;
                }
                #pageNumber {
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: -11px;
                    margin-top: -15px;
                }

                #pageNumber:after {
                    counter-increment: page;
                    content: "Page No: " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                }

                .contable{
                    border-right:1px solid black;
                    border-left:1px solid black;
                    border-top: 1px solid black;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                }

                .footNote{
                    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 12px;
                }

                .nopad{
                    padding:0px;
                }

                div.header {
                    position: running(header);
                    padding-top:20px;
                }
                .pagenumber:before {
                    content: counter(page);
                }
               .pagecount:before {
                    content: counter(pages);
                }
                .content{width:800px;/*margin-top:122px;*/}
                .watermark {
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-image: url("{!$Label.MktpQuoteDraftURL}");
                    background-position: center;
                }
                .watermark-img{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 90%;
                    height: 90%;
                    top: 20%;
                    left: 10%;
                }
            </style>
```

and vf component is added in the vf page. Will above styles be applied to the vf component automatically?

PS.  i am trying to add watermark and page number on vf component which is called in the vf page. the vf page and the component makes up a document. vf page is render as pdf

Comment: as long as the custom component's styleClass matches the CSS selectors, it should work fine as the custom component(s) just render HTML within the outer VF page HTML. @Mamed comment is relevant, only CSS 2.1 is supported for PDF

Answer (score 1):

Applying CSS while rendering as PDF is tricky thing.
Read this (I know we do not like to read, but here we have to ;) )

[Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm)

I you render as pdf I suggest you to use [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and table related component instead of CSS